# Octave faster load

Tags: octave, data-import

i have a huge amount of data saved in a text file that i want to load into octave.  the data is too big to load all at once with the dlmread function so at the moment i loop through a procedure that loads sections of the data; does calculation on each section and; eventually aggregates all these calculations.

`X = dlmread(data_source, ",", [load_pointer, x_load_offset, load_pointer + load_max - 1, input_layer_size + x_load_offset]);
y = dlmread(data_source, ",", [load_pointer, 0, load_pointer + load_max - 1, 0]);`

this is extremely slow and i have to call this loop multiple times within my code.  was thinking of converting the original data into octave native format to speed up this process but not sure how to do this especially considering that i can't load my original data all at once (i.e., would need to load partial data, save and append my next loads/save).  can anybody help with this?

thanks,

Comment: if you are worrying about this, I'm guessing you will want to load the data in this file multiple times. If that's the case, it may be simpler to simply suffer reading the whole file once (single call to `dlmread()` for simplicity sake), and then just save it with `save -binary foo.dat foo`

Comment: the problem is that the single call crashes due to lack of memory (using 32 bit octave) hence why i'm forced to break up my loads ...

Comment: in that case, are you sure that you can read it all, by reading in pieces and appending to the end? You should have the same problem.  The only thing I can think of, is if each time you read, you read it into a cell, but that will complicate the handling of your data.

Comment: well i would read to octave native file in pieces but at least each load (of a section) would be faster.  i guess my question is how to i append when a save a file?

Comment: oh, nevermind -append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get something like:

```
error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type
```

Doesn't really mean that you don't have enough memory.  It means that the resulting matrix would be too big to index.  You have built Octave with 32 bit index which means that the maximum number of elements in anything is:

```
octave> sizemax 
ans = 2147483646
```

The end result is that it doesn't matter whether you read it on chunks or all at once, you won't be able to have a single array with all your data if it has more elements that the `sizemax` limit (exception for sparse matrices).

What you can do though, is to read your chunks of data into a cell array. This will complicate any further analysis you want to do at our data. The best way to read is dependent on your problem.  If you want to all compare things in the same column, you may place each column into a cell element, like so:

```
data = cell (1, ncolumns);
data(1) = csvread (data_source, [0 0 double(sizemax) 0]);
data(2) = csvread (data_source, [0 1 double(sizemax) 1]);
[...]
```